# Can I set <p class="pull-right"> inside <td> in an HTML table?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to set header in table with the header name in center, and with serial number on right.  How can I set that??

This is my example code :

```
<tr class="header"> 
    <td colspan="3"  >
     PAKET ALAT GELAS
     <p class="pull-right" style="font-size:11px;">NO. <?php echo $date ;?><p></td>
</tr>
```

and this is my style :

```
table tr.header td {
    font-size:18px;
    height:30px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:20%;
    margin: 10px auto;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: You are using Bootstrap 2.x ?

Comment: i use Bootstrap v3.3.6, pull right inside <td> doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can check this. [See DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Lu85g8rL/13/)

Don't forget to check the

> External Resources menu from left side.

Sample Code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr class="header"> 
    <td colspan="3" >
     PAKET ALAT GELAS
     <p class="pull-right" style="font-size:11px;">NO. 1<p></td>
</tr>

<tr class="header"> 
    <td colspan="3" >
     PAKET ALAT GELAS
     <p class="pull-right" style="font-size:11px;">NO. 2<p></td>
         <td colspan="3" >
     PAKET ALAT GELAS
     <p class="pull-right" style="font-size:11px;">NO. 3<p></td>
         <td colspan="3" >
     PAKET ALAT GELAS
     <p class="pull-right" style="font-size:11px;">NO. 4<p></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I try in demo, that workly.. but i use bootstrap css

Comment: @YanuarIhsan which version of bootstrap ? Try to use latest.

Comment: I use Bootstrap v3.3.6, pull right inside <td> doesnt work

Comment: I've also used Bootstrap v3.3.6 in demo. Load the CSS files properly.

Comment: That's right, i use bootstrap css in demo, and thats work properly, but in my project doesn't work, i use to create pdf html